# can't display movies using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to show a video when my view is launched.  But I keep getting Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target (my view controller).

Here is my code.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayerViewController *moviePlayer;

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    
    NSString *documentsDirectory31 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentaryDirectory23 = [documentsDirectory31 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChildOne.txt"];
    
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: documentaryDirectory23]) {
        self.user.text =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentaryDirectory23 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    }
    self.sharingtext.hidden = YES;
    
   AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    
    NSString *audioName = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
    NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *slash = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"];
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [slash stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.user.text];
    
    //Get a full path to the image in the documents directory.
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
    
    
  NSString *fullPatha = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPatha];
   
    NSLog(@"fullPatha:%@",fullPatha);
  NSData *videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
       AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    
    
    self.sharingImage = [UIImage imageWithData:videoData];
    //AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
   
    // frame must match parent view
    [self.view insertSubview: [moviePlayer view]atIndex:4];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        }
        
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667);
        }
        
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414,736);
        }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 812.0){
              //11pro76*1.17, 3*1.69 OK!
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 11 pro/12mini/SE2");
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 896.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 11");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 844.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 12/pro");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 926.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 12PROMAX");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
        
        
        else {
            [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
        }
        
    }
    
    moviePlayer.player = playVideo;
    [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:^{
        [self->moviePlayer.player play];
    }];
  }
```

I know the file exists at the path because when I shoot and save it I can share it to iMovie.
I'm not sure why the modal view is nil.
Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have found the bugs in the code. you have create the instance of AVPlayerController but you forgot to give in memory address. kindly paste below code and you are ready to fly..

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayerViewController *moviePlayer;


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.moviePlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

 NSString *documentsDirectory31 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentaryDirectory23 = [documentsDirectory31 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChildOne.txt"];
    
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: documentaryDirectory23]) {
        self.user.text =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentaryDirectory23 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    }
    self.sharingtext.hidden = YES;
    
   AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    
    NSString *audioName = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
    NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *slash = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"];
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [slash stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.user.text];
    
    //Get a full path to the image in the documents directory.
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
    
    
  NSString *fullPatha = [fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPatha];
   
    NSLog(@"fullPatha:%@",fullPatha);
  NSData *videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
       AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    
    
    self.sharingImage = [UIImage imageWithData:videoData];
    //AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
   
    // frame must match parent view
    [self.view insertSubview: [moviePlayer view]atIndex:4];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        }
        
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667);
        }
        
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736.0){
            moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414,736);
        }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 812.0){
              //11pro76*1.17, 3*1.69 OK!
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 11 pro/12mini/SE2");
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 896.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 11");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 844.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 12/pro");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
       else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 926.0){
           NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED 12PROMAX");
                   //1176*1.29, 3*1.867 OK!
           moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
       }
        
        
        else {
            [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
        }
        
    }
    
    moviePlayer.player = playVideo;
    [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:^{
        [self->moviePlayer.player play];
    }];
  }
```

Comment: this didn't work.  Since there is already an alloc for the AVPlayer I get a error of Underfined symbol when I alloc moviePlayer.  However if I comment out the part about presenting the viewcontroller I have eliminated the error but the video doesn't show up. I will create a new post to figure that out.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry my dumb, Although I have added #import <AVKit/AVKit.h> in .h I hadn't added AVKit foundation to project.